# How to update the state of an object dynamically?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a reusable updateComponentHandler that would update the state of any selected component based on the value returned via various input fields.

Usually one would use something like this:

```
updateComponentHandler = value => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    let selected = prevState.usedComponents
      .filter(item => item.selected === true)
      .shift();
    selected.backgroundColor = value;
    return { selected};
  });
};
```

However, in order for this to be truly reusable I can't hardcode the backgroundColor because there will be cases that require some other property to be updated. Because of this in my input components I'm returning both the property and the value that needs to be updated like this:

```
handleChange={color =>
  this.props.updateComponent({ backgroundColor: color.hex })
}
```

which returns for example backgroundColor: "#CCCCCC"

My problem is that I can't figure out how to insert this value to setState where one would use "selected.backgroundColor = value;" from the top example. 
Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to do, but one thing you can do is pass the key of the object in the state and do `selected[key] = value`.

```
updateComponentHandler = (key, value) => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    let selected = prevState.usedComponents
      .filter(item => item.selected === true)
      .shift();
    selected[key] = value;
    return { selected };
  });
};

handleChange={color =>
  this.props.updateComponent('backgroundColor', color.hex)
}
```

Comment: @GoranTesic if that solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that. I couldn't accept your answer for 5 minutes after I tested it, so I just now remembered to come back and accept it. Thanks again.